# Duplicate Edge in Prim's Minimum Spanning tree

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, github-codereviews

I've created a generic data structures and algorithm library written in C.
I've tried to implement Minimum Spanning tree using the Prim's Algorithm

When I run the code for a bi directional graph, I see that the reverse edge also gets added as part of the MST() creating a duplicate edge and increasing the overall MST tree cost.

The Code implementation is as given below,

[graph.h](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/blob/master/ds/graph/graph.h)

```
/*! @file graph.h
    @brief 
    Contains declations of graph types, operations and structure
*/
#pragma once
#include "common.h"
#include "link_list.h"

/// graph Vertex
typedef struct gnode {
    t_gen id;           ///< Pointer to store Data
    int idx;            ///< Index of vertex in adaceny list
    t_linklist *neigh;      ///< Link List to neighbor vertices(nodes)
} t_gnode;

/// graph neighbor edges represented in neigh list
typedef struct gedge {
    t_gnode *node;          ///< Pointer to neighbor vertex
    int weight;         ///< Cost of the edge
} t_gedge;

// fn ptr for adding weighted edge
typedef t_gen (*f_wedge)(t_gen, t_gen, t_gen, int); 

/// graph struct defn
typedef struct graph {
    // graph info params
    char *name;         ///< Graph Instance Name
    int count;          ///< Vertex Count of graph
    int max_size;           ///< Max Vertex count of graph
    int total_edges;        ///< Edge count of graph

    // graph nodes
    t_gnode *nodes;         ///< Adaceny List Representation of graph vertices

    // graph routines
    f_gen2 add_vertex;      ///< routine to add a vertex in graph
    f_gen2 del_vertex;      ///< routine to del a vertex in graph
    f_gen3 add_edge;        ///< routine to add an edge in graph
    f_gen3 del_edge;        ///< routine to del an edge in graph
    f_gen3 add_edge_sym;        ///< routine to add a symmetric edge in graph
    f_gen3 del_edge_sym;        ///< routine to del a symmetric edge in graph
    f_wedge add_wedge;      ///< routine to add a weighted edge in graph
    f_wedge add_wedge_sym;      ///< routine to add a weighted symmetric 
    f_find find;            ///< routine to find a vertex in graph
    f_len len;          ///< routine to get vertex count in graph
    
} t_graph;


/// Dist info
typedef struct dist_info {
    t_gedge edge;           ///< Pointer to edge
    t_gnode *parent;        ///< Pointer to Vertex vertex
} t_distinfo;
```

[graph.c](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/blob/master/ds/graph/graph.c)

```
/*! @brief  
 *  Find the Minimum Spanning for weighted undirected graph
 *  Using Prim's Algorithm
 *  @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm
 *  @param d     - Pointer instance of graph
 *  @return      - Pointer to dist array to all nodes in graph
 */
t_gen prims_mst(t_gen d)
{
    t_graph *g = (t_graph*)d;
    t_gedge *v, *u;
    t_llnode *cur, *end;
    t_linklist *neigh_list;
    t_distinfo *dist, *tmp;
    t_heap *h;
    t_dparams dp;
    t_gen *pq;

    // Data specific operation for generic min heap
    init_data_params(&dp, eUSER);
    dp.free     = dummy_free;
    dp.cmpr     = graph_wedge_cmpr; 
    dp.cmpr_idx = graph_wedge_cmpr_idx;
    dp.swap_idx = gen_swp_idx;
    dp.copy_idx = gen_cpy_idx;
    dp.get_idx  = gen_get_idx;

    // Creating a generic min heap to store edges
    pq   = get_mem(g->count, sizeof(t_gen));    
    h    = create_heap("Dijkstra's Heap", pq, g->count, eMIN_HEAP, &dp);
    
    // Initalize all dist to all nodes as infinite 
    dist = get_mem(g->count, sizeof(t_distinfo));   
    for (int i = 0; i < g->count; i++) {
        dist[i].edge.node   = &g->nodes[i];
        dist[i].edge.weight = INT_MAX; 
        dist[i].parent      = NULL;
    }
    
    
    // Set 0 as start vertex
    h->insert(h, &dist[0].edge);
    while (h->empty(h) != true) {
        // Of the edges that connect the tree to vertices not yet in the tree,
        // Find the minimum-weight edge, and transfer it to the tree
        u = h->extract(h);

        neigh_list = (t_linklist*)u->node->neigh;
        cur = neigh_list->head_node(neigh_list);
        end = neigh_list->end_node(neigh_list);
        while (cur) {
            v = (t_gedge*)cur->data;
            
            // If cur edge weight is greater than new edge
            // and the end vertex is not visited
            if (dist[v->node->idx].edge.weight > v->weight) {
                // Set new edge as part of MST, update parent
                // and add edge to heap
                dist[v->node->idx].edge.weight = v->weight;
                dist[v->node->idx].parent = u->node;
                h->insert(h, &dist[v->node->idx].edge);
            }
            
            // Exit after neigh list traversal complete
            cur = neigh_list->next_node(neigh_list, cur);
            if (cur == end) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Destroy heap and destroy the array used for storing heap
    h->destroy(h);
    free_mem(pq);

    return dist;
}
```

Can somebody help me figure out how to remove the reverse(duplicate) edge from the MST.

Heap implementation[here](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/tree/master/ds/heap).

Complete Graph implementation [here](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/tree/master/ds/graph).

Link  list implementation that forms the adjacency list [here](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/tree/master/ds/link_list).

Link to Github repo [here](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to conceiving your graph as "bidirectional" instead of *undirected*.  The former would be an implementation detail that should be invisible to clients.  The latter is a semantic description of a graph to which Prim's could apply.

Comment: Overall, though, you have presented far too much code.  Unless you reduce the problem to a [mre], we are unlikely to be able to help you.

Comment: @Mohammed Meraj - If you read the Wikipedia article referred to in the code comment, you'll realize that the `Graph 2` you use for the test cannot have a spanning tree, as of its ten vertices only seven are connected.